# Which is the default sorting mode of mail downloading.?

Tags: email

I am working on mail client so once i start downloading my mail it will appear as a randomly so i am confus. 
so i want to know which is the default mode of sorting means ascending or descending.

Thanks...!!

Comment: What protocol are you using to get the mail from the mail server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IMAP to fetch the mail from the remote server, the mail will be ordered by ascending IMAP UID.  By default, [the higher the number, the more recently it was added to the folder](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1):

```
Unique identifiers
are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the [folder]; as each
message is added to the [folder] it is assigned a higher UID than the
message(s) which were added previously.
```

However, that doesn't mean that messages are downloaded in ascending date order via IMAP.  If you move a message from one folder to another, it gets a new UID and is moved to last place in the new folder.  And if the IMAP UID Validity Value is reset, all bets are off -- the messages could be renumbered in any order whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Ascending by date would put newest emails at the top of list. This is the default sort order I've seen in email clients.

Comment: ok but i had made a mail client and i was dowload mail so it was appear as a randamly so this is also in a ascending order. ?